# Copy from Visual Studio 2015 code with line numbers and highlights

Tags: c#, ms-word, visual-studio-2015, code-formatting

I'm composing a programming guide for users so I need to copy some pieces of code from MS Visual Studio 2015 to MS Office 2016. I tried different ways (even by using Notepad++). They didn't provide me the satisfactory result. I want the pasted text to be as formated as in Visual Studio including lines numerations. in I'd like to export code from VS to rtf, for example, and paste it into the Word file. I did the same thing using [Copy as HTML](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/98fef791-eb65-4cdf-bf84-077b98c234cf) extension for Visual Studio 2013. Do you have any solutions or ideas?

UPD: I don't want to use screenshots. I want to past some text .docx to be successfully converted to PDF.

Comment: Short of taking a screenshot, I don't see how you could do that. Perhaps pasting it into Excel and adding line numbers in the first column before pasting it back is an option?

Comment: @MartijnK I don't want to use screenshots because they are not scalable. After converting to PDF they often go the wrong way. At all I'm looking for a way to paste a text.